# Wierd anti-aliasing in java graphics

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d, antialiasing

I came across to this wierd anti-aliasing:

[image]

The left shape and the right shape exactly shares the curve part. However, a black curve appears and interrupt the smoothness of the drawing and colors. This is a sample, and it intends to show the issue.

At first, with different colors, I thought it was optical illusion, (turn on and off the commented CHECK_# lines below). But when used the same color, this happened.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class darkBorders extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //g2.setColor(Color.WHITE); //CHECK_1
        g2.fill(g2.getClip());

        int r = 100;

        g2.translate(this.getWidth() / 2 - r, this.getHeight() / 2 - r);

        Path2D p = new Path2D.Double();
        p.moveTo(0, 0);
        p.lineTo(r, 0);
        p.quadTo(2 * r, r, r, 2 * r);
        p.lineTo(0, 2 * r);
        p.closePath();
        g2.setColor(new Color(0xFF9900));
        //g2.setColor(new Color(0x00CC66));  //CHECK_2
        g2.fill(p);

        p.reset();
        p.moveTo(2 * r, 0);
        p.lineTo(r, 0);
        p.quadTo(2 * r, r, r, 2 * r);
        p.lineTo(2 * r, 2 * r);
        p.closePath();
        g2.setColor(new Color(0xFF9900));
        g2.fill(p);


        g2.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new darkBorders());
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can fix this issue?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by using `double` values for your coordinates. Next, don't use `fill(clip)`, the clip rectangle won't always match the component coordinate space (which has been translated).  Set the panel's `backgroundColor` to `BLACK` and simply call `super.paintComponent` and let it fill the background

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the are always helpful. This is a sample code to show the problem. Path2D accepts both float and decimal values, so using integer values with cast them to double values at the end.

Comment: I used `2d` for example, while it don't solve the problem directly, it made it a lot better.  I also use a `BasicStroke` set to about `1.5f` which seemed to make a difference

Answer (score 2):

Besides a `fill` (fills the interior) do also a `draw` (draws the outline).
I am moving on thin ice, but you might do something with the pen stroke width.

Comment: I tried that, but it thickens the shape and did not work on alpha colors as it shows the regions. It works fine on other drawing apps (Flash, AI), but with java, this is what I get.

Comment: Although for the moment, I use that trick, but I would like to find an answer for it.

Comment: Maybe `g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0));`? Dubious, but should set stroke width to 0. IMHO anti-aliasing on seems the problem; first on black background, then on something between orange and black background. Hence I came up with a `draw`.

Comment: new BasicStroke(1.5f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND)  does the trick for me. It covers some regions of outer and inner parts of the shape. value 0 makes no difference as it is the smallest visible line supported by the device.

BTW, thanks for your help